# Enabling the Power State Change Beep

Tags: security, thinkpad, system-sounds

I have a Thinkpad T430s. I found on other Thinkpads there's a beep when you plug or unplug the AC cord. While I hear a lot of people say it's annoying it seems like a very useful security feature. However, when I go into the Power Manager the option to beep on plugging/unplugging ("Power State Change Beep") isn't there, even though it's in the help file already.

I know it would be easy to rig a software solution to this event, but it would kind of defeat the purpose if it doesn't beep when it's in sleep. Is there a way to get this beep on my laptop?

Comment: Have you checked for options in the BIOS?

Comment: Not in there :(

Answer (score 0):

I enabled this on my ThinkPad Edge. The setting is in the BIOS, so you would have to look in there for it.